# How to write event logs into xml files with SLF4J or Logback?

Tags: xml, logging, slf4j, logback

I want to create a customized log viewer and I need to integrate log files generated in .Net and Java platforms. First of All I want to know if I could write log events into a well-formed xml format with SLF4J or logback.
Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

logback-classic supports the log4j XML layout. See here: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html

Regarding SLF4J: it is a logging facade, rather than a logger. It provides a convenient way to decouple your logging API from the implementation, allowing you to change the actual logging library later. However, it won't log anything else itself, so you can't configure it to use XML.

If you want to use The SLF4J API and logback to perform the actual logging, you will need the appropriate logback binding jar. You can find it on the SLF4J web site.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at one of my answers to a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149409/why-are-log-files-commonly-flat/7219449#7219449). It's about log4j, but it's valid for logback as well.